# SQLite update query works in console, not in .Net

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, sqlite

I am using an SQLite database in my application. For some reason the query:

```
    UPDATE USERS SET PASSWORD = 'test' WHERE USERNAME = 'Admin'
```

works in console (updates the PASSWORD field), but when I run it via code:

```
Dim exec As String = "UPDATE USERS SET PASSWORD = '" & password & "' WHERE USERNAME = '" & username & "'"
Dim returnCode As [Boolean] = True
Try
    ExecuteNonQuery(exec)
Catch
    returnCode = False
End Try
Return returnCode
```

The function always returns false, and the database is not updated. Here is the ExecuteNonQuery method:

```
Public Shared Function ExecuteNonQuery(sql As String) As Integer
    Dim cnn As New SQLiteConnection(dbConnection)
    cnn.Open()
    Dim mycommand As New SQLiteCommand(cnn)
    mycommand.CommandText = sql
    Dim rowsUpdated As Integer = mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cnn.Close()
    Return rowsUpdated
End Function
```

What am I doing wrong here? My code for creating a new row works fine, but updating doesn't.

Yes, I am aware this is unsafe, I originally had a bunch more safety checks, but I need to at least get it to work before doing so.

Comment: My first guess is that you are connected/attached to the wrong database.

Comment: That can't be the case, since my other methods for adding new rows work fine.

Comment: Dont concat SQL; use SQL parameters - try a user name of `D'Angelo Barksdale` and dont store passwords as plaintext.  Also Password is a reserved word and needs to be escaped

Comment: I know not to store it as plaintext, was just an example. Thanks for the tip about the reserved word, I will check it out and report back.

Comment: @Plutonix still nothing.

Comment: Found the issue, sqlite3.dll for some reason disappeared from the output folder, causing weird issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, sqlite3.dll did not get moved to the output folder along with the application, causing weird behavior and ultimately for the query to fail.

When I placed a copy of the dll into the output folder, everything worked  fine.